# Multi Modelos en una vista ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, model-view-controller

Hola soy nuevo en C# y MVC ASP NET y tengo la siguiente complicación. Estoy tratando de despelagar los datos de diferentes modelos en un solo view para utilizar estos datos en un form, a todo esto encontré que puedo (mezclar?) dos modelos o más en un modelo padre y jalar de este nuevo los datos de ambos modelos ... 
Si es el caso, ya lo he intentado pero no lo consigo.
Estos son mis modelos:

```js
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models
{
    public class Categories
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

}
```

```js
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models
{
    public class Departments
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En este otro modelo estoy tratando de juntar los 2 y además le estoy dado otras propiedades(no sé si esto sea posible)

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models
{
    public class Requests
    {
        List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Departments>  dep { get; set; }
        List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Categories> cat { get; set; }
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Proyecto")]
        public string Project { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Esquema")]
        public int SchemeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Días de expiración")]
        public int ExpirationDays { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Comentarios")]
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Categoría")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi error salé aquí sobre el Model diciendo que caresco de la definición 'GetNumerator'

```html
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.Requests

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nueva solicitud";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                   
  @{ int i = 1; }
  @foreach (var item in Model.DepartmentId){
 <option>

<strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</strong>
  </option>
 i = i + 1;
 }

 </select>
```

Muchas gracias un saludo a toda la comunidad :)

Comment: Creo que lo que requieres es hacer un viewModel, una clase en su proyecto de vista que contenga los tres modelos que requieres, y en la vista usas esta clase como model.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, veo que estás aprendiendo ASPnet MVC 5, este workshop te caerá bien: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY por cierto, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que ganes la primera medalla y veas cómo funciona el sitio. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra en la siguiente linea

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DepartmentId)
```

La instrucción foreach espera que la lista que se va a recorrer sea un objeto de una clase que implementa `IEnumerable`. En tu caso, la propiedad `DepartmentId` es de tipo `int`.

De acuerdo al modelo de la clase `Requests`, me parece que debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.dep)
```

Puesto que `dep` es una lista (que implementa `IEnumerable`)

Comment: Hola traté de hacer eso pero me con una tercera clase...

{
    public class ReqCatDep
    {
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Departments> Dep { get; set; }
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Categories> Cat { get; set; }
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Requests> Req { get; set; }

    }
}

Donde hago esto :

  foreach (var item in Model.Cat)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>item.Name</td>
            <td>item.Description</td>
        </tr>
    }
Y me dice que el error esta justo en   
foreach (var item in Model.Cat)
D: ???
(no permiten@)

Comment: en los comentarios ...

Comment: ¿Puedes compartirme más información sobre el error?. De ser posible, si me pones una imagen, me ayudaría a entender mejor el error que mencionas. A simple vista, está bien lo que tienes, sin embargo, me atrevo a pensar que el problema debe ser otro.

Comment: Hola no puedo comentar imagenes, lo siento, esto me tira:
Compilation Error

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IEnumerable<ReqCatDep>' does not contain a definition for 'Cat' and no extension method 'Cat' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<ReqCatDep>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:
Line 12:     @foreach (var item in @Model.Cat)
Line 13:     {
Line 14:         <tr>

Comment: ah ya... me parece que tu modelo no es el que está definido en la vista, al parecer, `Model` ya es un IEnumerable de tipo ReqCatDep. En ese sentido, cambia el foreach por lo siguiente `@foreach (var item in Model)`. Ahora el objeto item, debe tener la propiedad Cat.

Comment: No me deja accesar a los modelos si ocupa Model.Cat/Dep/Req ...no me deja jalar sus propiedades D:

Comment: A eso me refiero; las propiedades no están definidas en el objeto Model, puesto que Model es una Lista (un IEnumerable) de ReqCatDep. Intenta `@foreach (var item in Model){  ... tu html aquí ...  }` . El objeto `item` debe contener las propiedades de Cat/Dep/Req

Comment: si intento esto = "item.Cat" / no funciona me tira error 
y si intento = "item.Name"  / que es un propiedad del metodo tambien me tira error u.u

Answer (score 0):

Creo "ViewData" es lo que buscas. En tu controlador puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
       public ActionResult VerDetalles(int id)
        {
            //Logica de consultas 
            ViewData["MiTabla1"] = miTabla1;
            ViewData["MiTabla2"] = miTabla2;
            return View();
        }
```

Y en tu vista basta con lo siguiente para acceder a los campos de tus tablas :

var miTabla1 = ViewData["ComoLaNombreasteEnELControlador"] as MiTabla1;